# svn to git migration fails

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I have a subversion repository that has about 45000 revisions. I am trying to convert it to git but it keeps failing.

I have tried git svn clone, subgit, svn2git and the atlassian provided svn-migration-scripts.jar

git svn clone and the atlassian provide jar usage result in similar errors - perl.exe.dump

subgit gives me an out of memory error

svn2git gives a different error

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong/ if I am not allocating enough resources for the migrtation (memory/CPU etc...). Or, if there is something wrong with my SVN repo that is causing these to fails.

Any suggestions/ ideas on how to troubleshoot these issues? Also, does 45000 revisions make it a large repository?

Thanks

Comment: What specs does your machine have?

Comment: I have migrated large SVN repositories using `git svn`. It took a week or so (slow network), had to restart many times. And not a large machine.

Comment: I have tried it on a Windows 7 desktop with 8GB RAM. 2.3GHz Quad Core CPU. I have also tried it on a Linux (ubuntu precise 32 bit) VM that has about 1.5GB RAM (hosted on the Windows Desktop)

Comment: @vonbrand what do you mean by "restart many times." did you break the migration into chunks. Or, did you have to redo the same command multiple times.

Comment: @vonbrand ran the same command multiple times. I finally got it working with svn2git - after allocating more memory to my Ubuntu machine

Comment: I had to restart the command often, it failed due to timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can add a suggestion for SubGit.

Run "subgit configure" then add to SubGit config file (depending on your case it will be at "subgit/config" or "conf/subgit.conf") the following option:

```
[translate]
eols = false
```

Then run "subgit install" for the repository.
I hope this will help.